# How to use the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm adding some authentication into my Rails API only app like so in my application_controller.rb:

```
def is_admin
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    if User.find_by(:auth_token => token)
      value = true
    else 
      value = false
    end
  end
end
```

And in my controller:

```
admin = is_admin
if admin
  @voices = Voice.all.map do |voice| 
    voice.format
  end
else
  @voices = 'Something else'
end
```

When I'm logged in, everything works fine as expected, however when I'm not logged in, I get the following error: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".`

While not logged in, I was expecting to get the 'Something else' response, which I'd then go ahead and deal with it accordingly.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Well `value` is not even used. You can replace the body of the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method with just `User.exists?(auth_token: token)`. As to the rest of your problem - check the rails logs (`tail -f logs/development.log`) it will show you a trace of where render is called the first time.

Comment: I've changed the block inside `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` and works fine as you suggested. The problem is that I can't find the first render call on `development.log`. Every time is called, it seems to origin from my Controller (the one I'm working on) and it only happened if I use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token`. Let's say I manually set the value of `admin = false` instead of `admin = is_admin` I don't get the error.

Comment: To be honest, all I'm looking for is a way to identify whether the request is authorised or not. Then modify the response accordingly. Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` is meant to be used in a `before_action` filter which runs before the action. Or with an explicit return.

If you simply want to check if a user exists you would use `authenticate_with_http_token` which does not send a response.

```
# app/helpers/authorization_helper.rb
module AuthorizationHelper
  # returns true/false
  # sets @current_user if the request is authenticated 
  def authenticate!
    return true if @current_user  # avoid re-querying the DB
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      @current_user = User.find_by(:auth_token => token)
    end
  end

  def is_admin?
    authenticate!
  end
end

# app/controllers/api_controller.rb
# or whatever controller you use as a base
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include AuthorizationHelper
end

# in your controller
def index
  if is_admin?
    @voices = Voice.all.map do |voice| 
    voice.format
  else
    @voices = 'Something else'
  end
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this in addition or rather an option to max's answer.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  def authorization!
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      @current_user = User.find_by(:auth_token => token)
    end

    unless @user.present?
      # You could return anything you want if the response if it's unauthorized. in this
      # case I'll just return a json object 
      return render json: {
        status: 300,
        message: "Unauthorized access in the API"
      }, status: 401
    end
  end
end

# in your controller just add a before_action method
before_action :authorization

def index
  @voices = Voice.all.map do |voice| 
  voice.format
end
```

In this case you won't need to add an if statement in every request that requires an authentication.